# Swift class test weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, casting, kif

I'm using KIF 3.0, [JKExpandTableView](https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView) XCode 6.1.1 and Swift.

I want to get the `JKExpandTableView` using `waitForTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel` of `KIF` tester object.
In the image it cast the `UIView` to `UITableView` because if I cast it to `JKExpandTableView` there there a `break on exception xcode`

If I cast the `UITableView` (that in fact is a `JKExpandTableView` as you can see in the image) to `JKExpandTableView` it don't pass the `if let` statement.

Check the red rectangles in the image.

Why it don't make the cast to `JKExpandTableView`?

[image]

Comment: If I recall I think I might have had this issue and I think adding all of my swift files to the kif test target may have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is caused precisely because you *do* include `JKExpandTableView` in both the application and test targets. This means the cast is treating an `AppModule.JKExpandTableView` as a `TestModule.JKExpandTableView` and failing.

The solution in this case would be to make sure the `AppModule.JKExpandTableView` is publicly accessible, add `import AppModule` to your tests (using your own module names of course), then do something like:

```
let jkTableFilters = tableFilters as AppModule.JKExpandTableView
```